# How to obtain a trash can icon on the dektop (Xfce)

Tags: xfce, desktop, trash

On the desktop in Xfce 4.10, the trash can icon seems to be replaced by a pdf icon.

[image]

How can I replace it by a trash can icon?

Comment: If Xfce was installed by minimal packages, user must install any additional icon theme. To find out currently installed icon themes, run `ls /usr/share/icons` in Terminal or run `xfce4-appearance-settings` and see "Icons" tab.

Comment: @clearkimura Perfect, this solved my question. I did not know this. I invite you to repeat your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Expanded my comment into a proper answer i.e. "seems to be replaced a pdf icon"--no, that ugly icon is not just for pdf. More details below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system doesn't seem to have an appropriate icon theme. End users who have installed from standard CD/DVD bootable image of any distro should *not* face this problem.

### That "PDF icon"

No, that is not a "PDF icon" but rather a fallback icon provided by Xfce component (Xfdesktop). One way to discover this icon is to use `find` command with `*fallback*` as keyword.

```
$ find /usr/share/pixmaps/* -name *fallback*
/usr/share/pixmaps/xfdesktop/xfdesktop-fallback-icon.png
```

In Debian or Ubuntu, user can also use `dpkg` command to search with `fallback` as keyword then use `grep` filter the result for appropriate file name extension (usually PNG image, hence `.png`).

```
$ dpkg --search fallback | grep .png
xfdesktop4-data: /usr/share/pixmaps/xfdesktop/xfdesktop-fallback-icon.png
```

### Existing icon theme

To find out currently installed icon themes, run `ls /usr/share/icons` in Terminal. The following is example output for Xubuntu 14.04 (uses Xfce 4.10 with official Xubuntu icon theme and goodies).

```
$ ls /usr/share/icons
Adwaita                  gmusicbrowser.png  mini
default                  gnome              redglass
DMZ-Black                handhelds          ubuntu-mono-dark
DMZ-White                hicolor            ubuntu-mono-light
elementary-xfce          HighContrast       whiteglass
elementary-xfce-dark     Humanity           xchat.xpm
elementary-xfce-darker   Humanity-Dark
elementary-xfce-darkest  large
```

Else, run `xfce4-appearance-settings` and see "Icons" tab.

### Additional icon theme

If Xfce was installed by minimal packages, which is *without* packages of recommends or suggests, then user must install any additional icon theme afterwards.

Depending on which icon theme user has installed, the trash can icon will appear differently. The following screenshot shows two icon themes in Xubuntu 14.04.

[image: Icons theme compared in Xubuntu 14.04]

The default icon theme in Xubuntu 14.04 with dark icon theme on panel is "elementary Xfce dark" (left) and another icon theme is "Humanity".

Although not shown above, Xfce uses an icon theme called "Tango". This is recommended by meta-package for Xfce desktop environment and is included by default in Debian Xfce.

Anyway, user should install any icon theme to see the trash can icon.

Comment: Actually, it solved [another question of mine](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346310/why-is-there-no-icon-for-some-files-in-file-manager-xfce) as well. If you write a minimal answer there referring to your answer on this page, I can accept it as well.

Comment: @Karlo I don't prefer to write answers that I can't confirm myself; Some icon themes may not provide certain icons. Perhaps you could [self-answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) by mentioning which icon theme did you install and how it looks like afterward.

Comment: Most of the icon themes that were already in the list, such as MATE, gave me satisfactory icons.